# Click on td not working

Tags: jquery, click, html-table

I have a table created dynamically and assigned a click event, but this event don't work on all cells, only on a fixed row. What's my mistake, please help me.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>Page Title</title> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
               var cardRules = new Array();
                $.get('UserFile.txt', function(data){
                        cardRules = data.split('\n');
                        // console.log(cardRules.length);
                        for (i = 0; i<cardRules.length; i++) {
                           // console.log(cardRules[i]);
                           var cardParts = cardRules[i].split(",");
                           // console.log(cardParts.length);
                           var out = "<tr>";
                           for (y = 0; y<cardParts.length; y++) {
                              // console.log(cardParts[y].replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace(/"/g, ''));
                              // out += "<td>" + cardParts[y].replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace(/"/g, '') + "</td>";
                              out += "<td>Part " + i + " " + y + "</td>";
                           }
                           out += "</tr>";
                           // console.log(out+'\n');
                           $('#tab').append(out);
                        }
                    });

                    $('#tab tr td').eq(2).on('click', function() {
                        console.log("Klick");
                     });
            });      
        </script>
    </head> 
<body> 

<table id="tab" border="1">
<tr>
<td>col1</td>
<td>col2</td>
<td>col3</td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are only adding the `on` event to the 3rd column of each row.

Also, as @roasted said, you need to use the `on` event over the modified element, in this case, better than `document` or `body` just `#tab`:

Try this:

```
$('#tab ').on('click','tr td', function() {
    if($(this).index() == 2){
        alert("Klick");
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/imac/zTAW3/4/

Answer (score 1):

The 'index' indicating the 0-based position of the  elements.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>Page Title</title> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
               var cardRules = new Array();
                $.get('UserFile.txt', function(data){
                        cardRules = data.split('\n');
                        // console.log(cardRules.length);
                        for (i = 0; i<cardRules.length; i++) {
                           // console.log(cardRules[i]);
                           var cardParts = cardRules[i].split(",");
                           // console.log(cardParts.length);
                           var out = "<tr>";
                           for (y = 0; y<cardParts.length; y++) {
                              // console.log(cardParts[y].replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace(/"/g, ''));
                              // out += "<td>" + cardParts[y].replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace(/"/g, '') + "</td>";
                              out += "<td>Part " + i + " " + y + "</td>";
                           }
                           out += "</tr>";
                           // console.log(out+'\n');
                           $('#tab').append(out);
                        }
                    });

                    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#tab tr td.cel').on('click', function() {
            console.log("Klick");
             alert($(this).text());
        });
    });      
            });      
        </script>
    </head> 
<body> 

<table id="tab" border="1">
<tr>
<td>col1</td>
<td class="cel">col2</td>
<td>col3</td>
</tr>
    <tr>
<td>col1</td>
<td class="cel">col22</td>
<td>col32</td>
</tr>
    <tr>
<td>col13</td>
<td class="cel">col23</td>
<td>col33</td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

I believe that this way it works
http://jsfiddle.net/pborreli/pJgyu/

Answer (score 0):

You have to use delegation for dynamic added elements:

http://jsfiddle.net/UkVSh/

```
$(document).on('click', '#tab tr td', function () {
    if($(this).index() === 2)
      alert("Klick");
});
```

If you were waiting for DOM ready or put script code just before closing body tag, you could use #tab as delegate. Would be better than using document.

Comment: It is not working @roasted: http://jsfiddle.net/imac/zTAW3/5/ Only for the fist row.

Comment: Ok, i solved it. thanks for your support. See Steves post below.

Comment: Thats great but for other people which could have same problem, post your solution as an answer, please!